Can I use a simpler model (small R²) to get more statistically relevant results?
I am new to this kind of stuff.
I am currently writing a bachelor thesis that uses data from the European Social Survey (round 7). 4 important questions that I'm using were not answered by every respondent. Every respondent was asked 1 of the 4 questions. This reduces my sample size significantly (ca. 260). If i run a regression using only that variable I get significant results (at least $p < 0.05$). If i run the regression using a more complete model that I used for other questions, the missing values lead to an even smaller sample size, and get some statistically insignificant results.
Can I present the single variable regression (obviously also has a much lower $R^{2}$) to provide statistically significant results?
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-3} 
\\[-1.8ex] & allbpe & allbpne \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2)\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 skill & $-$0.184$^{**}$ & $-$0.227$^{**}$ \\ 
  & (0.087) & (0.092) \\ 
  & & \\ 
 Constant & 2.464$^{***}$ & 2.828$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.063) & (0.062) \\ 
  & & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & 341 & 340 \\ 
R$^{2}$ & 0.013 & 0.018 \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.010 & 0.015 \\ 
Residual Std. Error & 0.540 (df = 339) & 0.568 (df = 338) \\ 
F Statistic & 4.472$^{**}$ (df = 1; 339) & 6.055$^{**}$ (df = 1; 338) \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-3} 
\\[-1.8ex] & alpfpe & alpfpne \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2)\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 skill & $-$0.261$^{***}$ & $-$0.229$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.073) & (0.081) \\ 
  & & \\ 
 Constant & 2.042$^{***}$ & 2.226$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.051) & (0.060) \\ 
  & & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & 340 & 348 \\ 
R$^{2}$ & 0.037 & 0.022 \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.034 & 0.020 \\ 
Residual Std. Error & 0.451 (df = 338) & 0.507 (df = 346) \\ 
F Statistic & 12.850$^{***}$ (df = 1; 338) & 7.910$^{***}$ (df = 1; 346) \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-5} 
\\[-1.8ex] & alpfpe & alpfpne & allbpe & allbpne \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4)\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 skill & $-$0.222$^{***}$ & $-$0.135 & $-$0.084 & $-$0.188$^{*}$ \\ 
  & (0.080) & (0.097) & (0.106) & (0.097) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 agea & $-$0.007$^{***}$ & 0.003 & $-$0.005 & 0.001 \\ 
  & (0.002) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.003) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 gndr & $-$0.008 & 0.034 & 0.083 & $-$0.073 \\ 
  & (0.080) & (0.090) & (0.093) & (0.094) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 hinctnta & $-$0.008 & $-$0.019 & $-$0.026 & 0.014 \\ 
  & (0.016) & (0.020) & (0.021) & (0.019) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 ctzcntr & 0.204$^{*}$ & 0.023 & 0.159 & 0.148 \\ 
  & (0.116) & (0.116) & (0.125) & (0.129) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 acetalv & 0.047 & 0.021 & $-$0.073 & $-$0.226$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.061) & (0.069) & (0.071) & (0.070) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 domicil & $-$0.020 & 0.124$^{**}$ & $-$0.019 & 0.088$^{*}$ \\ 
  & (0.041) & (0.049) & (0.049) & (0.051) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 lrscale & 0.030 & 0.081$^{***}$ & 0.122$^{***}$ & 0.144$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.022) & (0.023) & (0.023) & (0.024) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 Constant & 2.005$^{***}$ & 1.158$^{***}$ & 1.989$^{***}$ & 1.986$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.349) & (0.400) & (0.412) & (0.410) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & 282 & 266 & 286 & 280 \\ 
R$^{2}$ & 0.088 & 0.110 & 0.114 & 0.210 \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.061 & 0.082 & 0.088 & 0.187 \\ 
Residual Std. Error & 0.436 (df = 273) & 0.480 (df = 257) & 0.516 (df = 277) & 0.511 (df = 271) \\ 
F Statistic & 3.276$^{***}$ (df = 8; 273) & 3.978$^{***}$ (df = 8; 257) & 4.453$^{***}$ (df = 8; 277) & 9.002$^{***}$ (df = 8; 271) \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{4}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For starters, there is a great, free resource on handling missing data: Flexible Imputation of Missing Data

Show the result of $\LaTeX$, not the markup.

Study statistical principles and use subject matter knowledge to pre-specify a model that makes sense, adjusting for things that should be adjusted for.  Then don’t handle missing values in an ad hoc way but use well-studied methods such as multiple imputation with predictive mean matching to not discard incomplete data.  And lose the idea that ‘significant results’ is very meaningful.
